# Regex to validate email address to pass Amazon validation

Tags: regex, email-validation

I have looked through questions asked in Stack Overflow to answer my question, but haven’t come up with a solution. I am needing to validate email addresses with the Amazon email service validation in mind. Here are the rules I am trying to follow:

1. Dash cannot be preceded or followed by a period. Example: `.-` or `-.`
2. Dash cannot be at the beginning of the domain. Example: `grant.fox@-abcfinancial.com`
3. Dash cannot be at the end of the domain. Example: `grant.hill@abc.com-`

So far this is what I have come up with:

```
/^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/
```

Comment: And what exactly isn’t working?

Comment: So what about `^[^@]+@[^\W_](?:[\w-]+[^\W_])?(?:\.[^\W_](?:[\w-]+[^\W_])?)+$`?

Comment: That is close but this still passes: brian-.hill@abc.com

Comment: @BrianGray wasn't clear that the `.-` or `-.` combinations were in the name part of the email. One sec

Comment: Sorry about that buddy, and thanks for  the help!

Comment: This `^(?!.*(?:\.-|-\.))[^@]+@[^\W_](?:[\w-]+[^\W_])?(?:\.[^\W_](?:[\w-]+[^\W_])?)+$`?

Comment: Sorry for all the questions and I really appreciate your help, would you happen to know why this email would not be working? 

test.test@te.st-test.de

Comment: `^(?!.*(?:\.-|-\.))[^@]+@[^\W_](?:[\w-]*[^\W_])?(?:\.[^\W_](?:[\w-]*[^\W_])?)+$` my bad @BrianGray

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ctwheels we have an answer

`^(?!.*(?:\.-|-\.))[^@]+@[^\W_](?:[\w-]*[^\W_])?(?:\.[^\W_](?:[\w-]*[^\W_])?)+$`